# TikZ overwrites gnuplot .gnuplot file

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, angle, degrees

I do not know if what I am bringing up is a feature or a bug.

I am trying to get a `cos x` trig plot in degrees generated by `gnuplot` and plotted by `TikZ`. My `.gnuplot` file looks like this:

```
set table "trig.cosinex.table"; set format "%.5f"
set angles degrees; set samples 500; plot [x=0:360] cos(x)
```

When I compile my `.tex` file with Tikz/lualatex, the `.gnuplot` file becomes

```
set table "trig.cosinex.table"; set format "%.5f"
set samples 500; plot [x=0:360] cos(x)
```

The `set angles degrees;` part is deleted.

The gnuplot-relevant line in my `.tex` file is:

```
\draw [domain=0:360, samples=500, smooth] plot[id=cosinex] function {cos(x)}; % anm I missing a prefix here?
```

Kindly note that:

a.  I hand generate the `.table` file from the `.gnuplot` file by running it through `gnuplot.`

b.  TikZ/lualatex does not generate a `.table` file even if it does not exist (contrary to manual?) but only overwrites the `.gnuplot` file.

My questions are:

1. How can I get `TikZ` to specify the angles to be degrees in the `.gnuplot` file that it overwrites? [If overwriting cannot be prevented.]
2. How to prevent `TikZ` from overwriting my `.gnuplot` file in the first place? [After hand-compilation with `gnuplot`, the `.table` is left untouched by `TikZ` during multiple compilations as specified but the `.gnuplot` file is altered as above. So, repeat hand-compilation produces a wrong `.table` file and does not give correct results.]

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding (b), are you running tex with shell escapes enabled?  Otherwise, it isn't allowed to call gnuplot and it just generates the .gnuplot file for you to use to generate the .table data.

Comment: I am using the vanilla flavoured `lualatex` and `xelatex` from TeXLive 2011. The log files show 'restricted \write18 enabled` for both formats. I believe that this is sufficient but would appreciate confirmation.

Comment: No, that's not sufficient.  The `restricted\write18` is allowed to execute a limited number of prespecified programs, of which gnuplot is not one.  You need to run `xelatex -shell-escape` (`lualatex` might have a different option for this).

Comment: Thanks. `--enable-write18` seems to work with both `xelatex` and `lualatex` on my system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `\draw ... plot ... function {<plot command>}`, the first thing TikZ does is generate the `.gnuplot` file with the default options and the `<plot command>`. Then it tries to execute `gnuplot` with the `.gnuplot` file. This is a feature (it's what `function` is supposed to do), and works as described in the manual.

If all you want to do is plot the `.plot` file generated by calling `gnuplot` manually, then you shouldn't use the `function` command, but simply `file`. In your case, you could use

```
\draw [smooth] plot file {texse.cosinex.table};
```

Note that the `domain`, `samples` and `id` keys have no effect when plotting data from a file.

---

If you want to use the `function` command (i.e. you want to generate the `.gnuplot` file from within TikZ) with degrees, you can use `raw gnuplot` to provide the appropriate options:

```
\draw [smooth] plot[id=cosinex, raw gnuplot] function {set samples 500; set angles degrees; plot [0:360] cos(x)};
```

Or you could change the `.gnuplot` skeleton using

```
\makeatletter
{
  \catcode`\%=12
  \catcode`\"=12
  \xdef\pgf@gnuplot@head{set table \noexpand\pgf@plottablefile@quoted; set angles degrees; set format "%.5f"}
}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble. Then you can plot your function as desired:

```
\draw [domain=0:360, samples=500, smooth] plot[id=cosinex] function {cos(x)};
```

Comment: Thank you. For invoking gnuplot, I needed to add `--enable-write18`; the default is not sufficient. I have tested out both solutions and they work. Only I am unsure why you have `x=0.2` in `\draw [smooth,x=0.2] plot file {texse.cosinex.table};`. Removing it gave me what I wanted. Parts of your answer would help being put into the pgfmanual.

Comment: @chandra: Ah, sorry, the `x=0.2` was necessary in my example document because otherwise the plot would have been much too wide.